# How to fill colour in Line using ctx html?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Please check this link
https://www.jovianarchive.com/content/charts/628003987200000000_.png.  i am creating same chart but all the lines and geometrical shapes are dynamic. in line there is colour with combination of balck and red (Look like stripe) want the same.
My code

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create a Path before call stroke method:

```
 canvas =     document.getElementById("canvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
 ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
 //point 0, 0
 ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
 //to point 300, 150
 ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
 ctx.closePath();

 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fill();
```

You can change the line width and add shadow. Look in my project:

https://codepen.io/Luis4raujo/pen/GRNEPXO

If this comments help u, vote in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider to create a pattern. You can create it from an image or from an off screen canvas. Here's a quick demo of the second way: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-khorana-ystxp?file=/index.html

More info about pattern creation in html canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern

Comment: thanks exactly i want like this but facing some another issue

Comment: in this case on some  position its not working

Comment: can you give me more details? I am not sure I understood

Comment: @AkshayBhardwaj hopefully I understood what you meant. I iterate my example to make the pattern work in all the line positions https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-khorana-ystxp?file=/index.html. I wrote some comments in the code to explain it

Comment: will check this .. i think this will work for me

Comment: ok, let me know if it works and the comments are clear, or more iteration is needed